# Rust Cacher implementation (chapter 13 of the Book)

Tags: rust

In https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html the author recommended to try to implement `Cacher` that:

1. Stores values in a `HashMap`
2. Allows the closure to be defined with various input/output types.

Here's my implementation of it:

```rust
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

struct Cacher<ClosureType, ParamType, ReturnType>
where
    ClosureType: Fn(ParamType) -> ReturnType,
    ParamType: Hash + Eq,
{
    calculation: ClosureType,
    values: HashMap<ParamType, ReturnType>,
}

impl<ClosureType, ParamType, ReturnType> Cacher<ClosureType, ParamType, ReturnType>
where
    ClosureType: Fn(ParamType) -> ReturnType,
    ParamType: Hash + Eq + Copy,
{
    fn new(calculation: ClosureType) -> Cacher<ClosureType, ParamType, ReturnType> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: ParamType) -> &ReturnType {
        if self.values.contains_key(&arg) {
            self.values.get(&arg).unwrap()
        } else {
            let result = (self.calculation)(arg);
            self.values.insert(arg, result);
            self.values.get(&arg).unwrap()
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn cacher_works_with_multiple_values() {
        let mut cacher = Cacher::new(|a: i32| -> i32 { a + 1 });

        let value = cacher.value(5);
        assert_eq!(6, value.clone());

        let value = cacher.value(10);
        assert_eq!(11, value.clone());
    }
}
```

The second task was much more "engaging" and I had some doubts about it:

1. As soon as I made `Cacher` generic with 3 type parameters, `HashMap` started to complain that it does not accept all the types. By guessing I figured I'll add trait bounds around the `ParamType` (that type will be the key in `HashMap`) to require both `Hash` and `Eq` traits' How do I make sure in such situation what trait bounds are necessary? I tried to find the source code of Rust's HashMap to see exactly which bounds they have defined for `K` and `V`, but I couldn't find that source code. I only found [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/library/std/src/collections/hash/map.rs#L209), but it refers to some `base`, which I did not understand.
2. I was wondering if the `value()` method should accept an owned type or maybe a reference? Also, I was wondering if it should return an owned type or a reference. In the end I went with owned type on input and a reference on output. Is it a good design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks very nice! First, answering your questions:

#### Q1: How do I make sure in such situation what trait bounds are necessary?

It is a combination of reading the documentation and intuition. If we Google something like "hashmap rust", we get to [the documentation page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html), which tells us what we need to know:

> It is required that the keys implement the `Eq` and `Hash` traits, although this can frequently be achieved by using `#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]`.

If you know how a hashmap works, this also makes sense. Keys in the hashmap have to be *hashed* to find their place in the table, which means the key type must implement `Hash`. Additionally, if two keys collide (have the same location in the table), we need to know if they are the same key, or different. Hence, the key type must also implement `Eq`. `PartialEq` is a requirement for `Eq` as it is a weaker version.

So you should be requiring `Eq` and `PartialEq`, but NOT `Copy`. As a general rule of thumb, avoid `Copy` as it is intended for easily-copyable types and makes your code less generic. Instead, use `Clone` which requires you to explicitly clone a value.

#### Removing the Copy trait

So, above I said you should remove the `Copy` trait bound on `ParamType`, as it's not required by `HashMap` and should be avoided.
Unfortunately, removing `Copy` usually requires you to think harder about where ownership flows in your program, but fortunately, it's a helpful exercise. :)
Once you replace `+ Copy` with `+ Clone`, the Rust compiler will complain about these lines:

```rust
let result = (self.calculation)(arg);
self.values.insert(arg, result);
self.values.get(&arg).unwrap()
```

What's happening here? In the first line, `self.calculation` is a function type that takes as input a `ParamType` (NOT a reference). So it needs to take ownership. So, we've already given away our value after the first line! We still need it around, so instead of giving it away, we should make a clone.
Similarly, the second line needs ownership in order to insert the parameter `arg` into the cache `self.values`. So we need two `.clone()` calls to please the compiler:

```rust
let result = (self.calculation)(arg.clone());
self.values.insert(arg.clone(), result);
self.values.get(&arg).unwrap()
```

Are two clones necessary?
Clones can be expensive -- you should be imagining that `arg` might be something large, like a string or a vector -- so we should make sure we aren't cloning unnecessarily.
It turns out the answer here is that you should be able to do it with one clone, but it's tricky, so I will not discuss it here.
You would need to use a special feature of hashmaps called the [Entry API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry).

However, there's an easier way: we can realize that the input parameter, `arg` is not used at the end of the function (it's been cloned twice, but the original owned value is not needed). So, we can be more efficient by accepting an `&arg` instead of `arg`. Here is our final code:

```rust
    pub fn value(&mut self, arg: &ParamType) -> &ReturnType {
        if self.values.contains_key(arg) {
            self.values.get(arg).unwrap()
        } else {
            let result = (self.calculation)(arg.clone());
            self.values.insert(arg.clone(), result);
            self.values.get(arg).unwrap()
        }
    }
```

Additionally, `cargo clippy` has some helpful suggestions for how to simplify this. We end up with this final version of the code (and we also have to update the unit tests appropriately).

```rust
    pub fn value(&mut self, arg: &ParamType) -> &ReturnType {
        if !self.values.contains_key(arg) {
            let result = (self.calculation)(arg.clone());
            self.values.insert(arg.clone(), result);
        }
        self.values.get(arg).unwrap()
    }
```

That leads us to your second question:

#### Q2: Is it better to accept/return an owned type or a reference? How can I tell?

If the type is `Copy`, just accept/return an owned type (copy means creating copies is easy). However now that we have made the code better to require `Clone`, this doesn't apply.
Here are two good questions to ask:

- If you are accepting an owned value, are you using it? If no, you should accept a reference instead. The answer here was no: we were `.clone()`ing the argument twice, but discarding it at the end. So we switched to a reference.
- If you are accepting a reference, are you cloning it *exactly once?* If yes, you should likely accept an owned value instead and avoid the clone. Here, we are cloning twice, not just once, so this doesn't apply.
- If you are returning a reference, could you instead return a value (is there a value in the function body that's available to return)? If yes, return the value instead. Here, the answer is no: the return value is stored inside the cache, so we can't take ownership over it without removing it from the cache. So, we can't return a value and can only return a reference.

A general rule of thumb is that *read-only* methods accept and return references, whereas methods which insert into a data structure accept owned values, and methods which delete from a data structure return owned values.
Here, the "data structure" is the cache, so your signature makes sense: it accepts an owned value because it's inserting into the cache, and it returns a reference to the return value in the cache.

#### Further advice

I realize this got a bit long, but a couple other things:

- Always try to remove warnings and run `cargo clippy`. Your code has some unused function errors, which it's best to avoid by making your data structure public: `pub struct Cacher`, `pub fn new`, `pub fn value`.
- Finally, you have a useless `fn main()` function. In this case, what you are writing is more of a library than a binary, so what you probably want is to rename `main.rs` to `lib.rs`. Then you can get rid of the main function.

#### Entry API

Since you are interested -- here's how to do it with [Entry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert_with):

```rust
    pub fn value(&mut self, arg: ParamType) -> &ReturnType {
        let result = (self.calculation)(&arg);
        self.values.entry(arg).or_insert(result)
    }
```

We can now remove `Clone`, but need to accept an owned `ParamType` rather than a reference (as in your new code) since we need an owned value to insert into the cache.

Comment: Thanks a ton for that review! While reading your remarks about `Copy`, I started modifying my code, I got to a little bit different result than you proposed. I've changed `ClosureType` to be like this: `Fn(&ParamType) -> ReturnType` So, the closure would accept a reference instead of owned type. The closure is supposed to be some simple transformation function that accepts x and returns y, it has no knowledge about storing data in cache (that's something that `Cacher` adds on top of the closure). I'll post new code as an additional answer.

Comment: I didn't know about `clippy`, it's nice! Probably some real IDE would have that functionality integrated to show me tips while I write the code. VS Code is quite poor for anything else than JS in my experience.

Comment: @Loreno That design makes sense too! As long as the user doesn't mind providing a closure with read-only access, that doesn't need an owned value. For VS Code, do you have [rust-analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matklad.rust-analyzer) installed? That's supposed to be much preferred over the default Rust support.

Comment: No, I had the "official" one installed. I replaced it now with the one you linked to, I'll see how it goes with that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code after some changes that I did after reading @6005's comment:

```rust
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

pub struct Cacher<ClosureType, ParamType, ReturnType>
where
    ClosureType: Fn(&ParamType) -> ReturnType,
    ParamType: Hash + Eq,
{
    calculation: ClosureType,
    values: HashMap<ParamType, ReturnType>,
}

impl<ClosureType, ParamType, ReturnType> Cacher<ClosureType, ParamType, ReturnType>
where
    ClosureType: Fn(&ParamType) -> ReturnType,
    ParamType: Hash + Eq + Clone
{
    pub fn new(calculation: ClosureType) -> Cacher<ClosureType, ParamType, ReturnType> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn value(&mut self, arg: &ParamType) -> &ReturnType {
        if !self.values.contains_key(arg) {
            let result = (self.calculation)(arg);
            self.values.insert(arg.clone(), result);
        }
        self.values.get(&arg).unwrap()
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn cacher_works_with_multiple_values() {
        let mut cacher = Cacher::new(|a: &i32| -> i32 { a + 1 });

        let value = cacher.value(&5);
        assert_eq!(6, value.clone());

        let value = cacher.value(&10);
        assert_eq!(11, value.clone());
    }
}
```

I changed the closure's type to accept a reference instead of owning the argument. I think it makes more sense for closures that are just supposed to transform some value into something else.

One thing that I don't like is that I have to `clone()` in the `value()` function. I feel like it should be possible to get rid of it completely, maybe using the Entry API that @6005 pointed at, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Since you are interested -- I added to my answer how to do it with [Entry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert_with): basically, `self.values.entry(arg).or_insert(result)`. We can now remove `Clone`, but need to accept an owned `ParamType` rather than a reference (as in your new code) since we need an owned value to insert into the cache.

Comment: @6005 You are awesome, thanks so much! So it looks a bit like I expected, and I like this new version much better.

Comment: You are welcome -- happy new year!